# Approximate the distribution of the sum of ind. Beta r.v

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X_i$ has a Beta distribution $\beta(1,K)$.

What is the best approximation for the distribution of $ S=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$, when the $X_{i}$ are independent and $N$ is finite.

Thanks

Comment: `Q: What is the best approximation?`.  Answer:  The exact solution. If not exact, it seems likely that, for any approximation that someone proffers, someone else could marginally improve on it.

Comment: Also, you might want to specify your functional form (parameters) since your Beta(1,K) might easily be my Beta(K,1), or vice versa for that matter.

Comment: but do we know the exact solution or any of these approximations ?     $\alpha=1,  \beta =K $

Comment: That is perhaps the point - in the absence of the exact solution, there is no absolute 'best' approximation. Even what works just 'well' might change depending on whether $n$ is large or small.

Comment: Ok, then can you please give me an approximation of the distribution of this sum ?

Comment: Have you specified your functional form yet?

Comment: Pdf= $\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1}$=        $ K (1-x)^{K-1}$

Comment: If $n$ is not very small, then the Central Limit Theorem is your friend ... i.e. a Normal approximation should do a reasonable job. If, however, $n$ is small, then some work will be needed ...

Comment: $n$ is small (let's say  $ n<10 $)